# Making abilities (Programming FFG's boardgame Descent)

Tags: architecture

I am trying to program Fantasy Flights boardgame "Descent - Journeys in the Dark", but I have hit a wall when dealing with implementing abilities, which are a crucial part of the game.

Abilities are used alot of different places, but are similar most of the time.

For a hero an ability could be: 
`At the start of his turn, Varikas the Dead recovers 1 fatigue`

I have written monsters with abilities like this: `Damage 2/Command`

Equipment/Treasures look like this: `When(TakingDamage):Exhaust&CancelDamage:2`, `When(MakingAttack(Type=Magic)):Gain:Surge 1` and `When(Equipped(State=StartOfTurn))):Discard&Hero.Healt=Hero.HealthMax&Hero.Fatigue=Hero.FatigueMax`

My idea is to maybe have some ability factory that will build an ability by reading the string formats, but I do not know how to implement them as a whole, and I am therefor turning to you.

Do any of you have any experience doing stuff like this, maybe when making D&D, Magic the Gathering, or maybe Descent?

Kind Regards
Thediabloman

Answer (score 2):

I've somewhat-implemented a solution to a similar problem to this when attempting to make a digital version of a card game, similar to Magic The Gathering.
I'm also reusing a similar model to this as I attempt to implement a D&D simulator, for player Feats.

The way I handled it was to create a series of "hooks", which were points in gameplay where an ability could potentially take effect.
For example, there was a hook at the start of a player's turn, before and after they drew a card, before and after they started their attack phase, etc.

I then implemented an "AbilityComponent" abstract class, which simply consisted of a single virtual function for each of those hooks. An implemented subclass would then implement the hooks appropriate to it.

From there, I created an "Ability" class which was little more than a collection of AbilityComponents, and some utility functions for managing them.

When the game ran, at each hook-point, all active effects would have their implementation of that hook called.

Following this model, you could theoretically build a string parser that, for each command, separates the command into Condition, Action, and Parameter, i.e.
{Condition}:{Action1}({Parameter1},{Parameter2})&{Action2}({Parameter1}); etc.

From there, just map each parsed action string to an instance of its related Ability class, and pass through the parameters.

Comment: +1 - Agreed, the Strategy pattern is the way to go here.